# sql query three tables (Employee,Role,Fees)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I`m trying to find all employees who have role Role.Type = 2 and have bigger Fees.Price then employee with Role.Type = 1 on same place (Role.PlaceID).

Table: Employee

- ID
- Name
- Type

Table: Role

- EmployeeID
- PlaceID
- Type

Table: Fees

- EmployeeID
- PlaceID
- Price

Can anyone assist me?

Edit: Some data example

Employee

```
ID Name Type
1  Name1 1
2  Name2 1
3  Name3 1
```

Role

```
EmployeeID  PlaceID  Type
1            1        1
2            2        1
3            2        2
```

Fees

```
EmployeeID  PlaceID Price
1             1      500
2             2      700
3             2      800
```

My query should return (Name3) as result because we have multiple employees in same place with both Role.Type = 1 and Role.Type = 2 and also Name3 as Role.Type = 2 have biggest Fees.Price then Role.Type = 1.

Comment: Could you edit your question to include some sample input and output?

Comment: ill show some data example, wait 3-4 mins

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not before my desk so I can't test it but it should work:

```
with EmplyeeWithMaxFee as
(
  select e.Id, e.Name, r.PlaceId, r.Type, Max(f.Price) as MaxFee
  from Emplyee e
  inner join Role r on r.EmployeeID = e.ID
  inner join Fees f on f.EmployeeID = e.ID
  group by e.Id, e.Name, r.PlaceId, r.Type
)

select e1.*
from EmplyeeWithMaxFee e1
where e1.Type = 2 and e1.MaxFee > (select Max(e2.MaxFee) from EmplyeeWithMaxFee e2 where e2.PlaceId = e1.PlaceId and e2.Id <> e1.Id and e2.Type = 1)
```

Comment: my question was not so good before edit, but you got my point. Perfect!!!

Answer (score 0):

Provide a sample of data and specify, what means 'have bigger Fees.Price'. But, maybe, something like that would work:

```
    SELECT Employee.* FROM Employee INNER JOIN Role ON Employee.ID = Role.EmployeeID 
INNER JOIN Fees ON Role.EmployeeId = Fees.EmployeeID AND Role.PlaceID = Fees.PlaceID
    WHERE Role.Type = 2 AND Fees.Price >= All (Select Fees1.Price FROM Role Role1 
INNER JOIN Fees Fees1 ON Role1.PlaceID = Fees.PlaceID WHERE Role.Type = Role1.Type)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your question correctly, a query like this one would solve your problem

```
SELECT EMP2.ID
FROM (SELECT ID, PLACEID, PRICE
      FROM EMPLOYEE, FEES
     WHERE EMPLOYEEID = ID AND TYPE = 2) EMP2,
   (SELECT ID, PLACEID, PRICE
      FROM EMPLOYEE, FEES
     WHERE EMPLOYEEID = ID AND TYPE = 1) EMP1
WHERE EMP2.PLACEID = EMP1.PLACEID AND EMP2.PRICE > EMP1.PRICE
```